# how to check the google-closure compiler version?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

The manifest file of google closure compiler latest jar shows this info. but i cant find the implmentation-version here.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.0
Built-By: lharker
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171-google-v7
Main-Class: com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute `java -jar compiler.jar --version`.